How to fix "resource_already_exists_exception" in ElasticSeach although the Index don't exist?
I am running a basic setup for ElasticSearch wie Docker and want to re-create an index within a Python application.
So the Idea is to delete an index if it already exists and then re-create it afterwards.
However, I get also an "recource_already_exists_exeption".
ElasticSearch: 8.7.0
Code:
es = Elasticsearch([{
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 9200,
    "scheme": "http"
}], request_timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)
print(es.info().body)

mappings = {
    "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "english"},
        "ethnicity": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
        "director": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
        "cast": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
        "genre": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
        "plot": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "english"},
        "year": {"type": "integer"},
        "wiki_page": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
}

index_name = "movies"
if es.indices.exists(index=index_name):
    print(f"Index '{index_name}' already exists, deleting...")
    es.indices.delete(index=index_name)

if es.indices.exists(index=index_name):
    print(f"Failed to delete index '{index_name}'")
else:
    print(f"Index '{index_name}' deleted successfully.")

time.sleep(1)

print("Creating index...")
es.indices.create(index=index_name, mappings=mappings)

I run elastic search via docker-compose:
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    restart: unless-stopped

How can I fix that behaviour?

There may be a data source which writes on the old index. Even if you delete, it can be recreated in between. Did you try to stop data with index.blocks.write?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/index-modules.html
